# Automatically name columns using R

Tags: r

This is my matrix in R:

```
n_forward=50

matriz=matrix(0,nrow=length(1:n_forward),ncol=16)
```

The number of rows depends of `n_forward` command.

from there I want to name de rows with this legends: t+1, t+2,....,t+(n_forward)

Is there any way to do this automatically, without having to do this below?

```
rownames(matriz)<-c("t+1","t+2","t+3","t+4","t+5","t+6","t+7","t+8","t+9","t+10","t+11","t+12","t+13","t+14","t+15","t+16","t+17","t+18","t+19","t+20","t+21","t+22","t+23","t+24","t+25","t+26","t+27","t+28","t+29","t+30", "t+31","t+32","t+33","t+34","t+35","t+36","t+37","t+38","t+39","t+40","t+41","t+42","t+43","t+44","t+45","t+46","t+47","t+48","t+49","t+50")
```

Comment: like this: 
`n_forward=101`

`matriz=matrix(0,nrow=length(1:n_forward),ncol=16)`
`rownames(matriz)<-paste0("t+", 1:length(n_forward))` ?

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I will edit the code. `n_forward=1:101`

`matriz=matrix(0,nrow=length(n_forward),ncol=16)`
`rownames(matriz)<-paste0("t+", 1:length(n_forward))`

Comment: If you run length(n_forward) it returns 1.  Instead you need to omit the length function.  So, rownames(matriz)<- paste0("t+", 1:n_forward) should work.

Comment: So which code worked, mine or that from @DiogoBastos ?

Comment: If `n_forward` could ever be `0`, then `seq_len(n_forward)` is safer than `1:n_forward`.  The first would return an empty vector, the second would return `c(1, 0)`.

Comment: I made a mistake in my first comment (I deleted it),  instead of `length(n_forward)` it should be `nrow(matriz)` so `rownames(matriz) <- paste0("t+", 1:nrow(matriz))`. I applogize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
n_forward=50
matriz=matrix(0,nrow=length(1:n_forward),ncol=16)
rownames(matriz)<-paste0("t+",1:n_forward)
```